# Fetch returns promise when I expect an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a simple api get request, but I can't seem to isolate the array on its own. its always inside of a promise and I'm not sure how to remove it or how to access the values stored in the array.

```
function getLocation(name) {

  let output = fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=oqAor7Al7Fkcj7AudulUkk5WGoySmEu7&q=london`).then(data => data.json());
  return output

}

function App() {

  var output = getLocation(`london`);
  console.log (output)
...
```

```
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(3)
```

is what is displayed in the console.log I require just the Array(3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch`, and `Promise#then`, **always** return a promise. To access the information it fetches, consume the promise:

```
getLocation()
.then(data => {
    // use the data
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report the error
});
```

or in an async function:

```
const data = await getLocation();
```

---

Side note: Your `getLocation` has a *very* common error (so common I [wrote it up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog): It doesn't check that the HTTP operation succeeded. `fetch` only fails on *network* errors, not HTTP errors. To fix it:

```
function getLocation(name) {
    return fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=oqAor7Al7Fkcj7AudulUkk5WGoySmEu7&q=london`)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: @TJCrowder this leads into another question, how do I take the .then(data => ... and set it to a variable that can be used outside of the function.

Comment: @blujay - Hi! You're not the only one with that question, people ask it a lot. :-) See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) may also be useful. Happy coding!

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks!! Amazingly, I noticed I'd missed it as I typed it but then forgot to go back and fix it.

Comment: @TJCrowder thanks, I'm still getting the hang of the => thing haha

Comment: @blujay - No worries! Just FWIW, it's not to do with the arrow function, it could be a traditional function and you'd have the same situation.